# VueJS Trigger action when Input File isn't shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

I'm trying to change the style of a div when a input file is clicked and change it again when the window to select a file is dismissed.

I can change the style for the first time when input is clicked, but I don't know how to change it again when I'm out of the file select window.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" ref="fileInput" v-on:click="changeStyle=true" v-on:change="previewFile">
    <div class="input-file-container" v-bind:style="[changeStyle ? activeBorderStyle : '']" @click="$refs.fileInput.click()">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
             stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 attach-file">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                  d="M18.375 12.739l-7.693 7.693a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364-6.364l10.94-10.94A3 3 0 1119.5 7.372L8.552 18.32m.009-.01l-.01.01m5.699-9.941l-7.81 7.81a1.5 1.5 0 002.112 2.13"/>
        </svg>
        <p style="font-style: italic" readonly >{{imgElegida}}</p>
    </div>
```

Initial state:

[image]

I click the div then i change the div border color:

[image]

I close the select file window and then I don't know what event should I listen to change again the style:

[image]

Comment: Maybe listen to the `blur` event? However there is no native event to check if the user has closed the OS-specific explorer/finder window opened by the input

Comment: Just tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

While you could listen to the input or change events and set `changeStyle=false` in the handler, this won't help if the user hits cancel.

One way is to listen to the `focus` event on `window`, and set `changeStyle=false` in there.

Demo below

```js
const {createApp} = Vue;
createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      changeStyle: false,
      activeBorderStyle: "border:solid blue 2px"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    previewFile() {
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('focus', e => {
      this.changeStyle = false;
    });
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.attach-file {
  width:24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" 
  style="display:none" 
  ref="fileInput" 
  @click="changeStyle=true" 
  @change="previewFile">
  <div class="input-file-container" 
    :style="[changeStyle ? activeBorderStyle : '']" 
    @click="$refs.fileInput.click()">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      fill="none" 
      viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
      stroke-width="1.5" 
      stroke="currentColor" 
      class="w-6 h-6 attach-file">
      <path 
        stroke-linecap="round" 
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        d="M18.375 12.739l-7.693 7.693a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364-6.364l10.94-10.94A3 3 0 1119.5 7.372L8.552 18.32m.009-.01l-.01.01m5.699-9.941l-7.81 7.81a1.5 1.5 0 002.112 2.13"/>
    </svg>
    <p style="font-style: italic" readonly>imgElegida</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked as I expected, thanks!